# Prevent child iFrame to get focus

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to prevent iFrame element to get focus or if not, at least to return focus instantly to parent window once such iFrame gets focus? Please advise with code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon what you're really trying to accomplish and which focus methods you are trying to prevent.  There's no magic setting you can set that prevents focus going to an iframe.

1. You can put a transparent element over the top of the iframe and have it capture all clicks so nothing in the iframe is clickable.  You can likely just position this with CSS and wouldn't necessarily need javascript unless the iframe size is dynamic or not known in advance.  This won't prevent javascript code from setting focus to the iframe, but will prevent mouse clicks from moving the focus to the iframe.
2. You can regularly check (javascript polling) where focus is and if it's not in your own document, then put it back in your document.  This is kind of a hack.

Here's a demo of the first option: http://bit.ly/10jzdlp

Comment: Is it possible to make such iFrame disabled to block a focus?

Comment: @Ωmega - I'm not aware of a disabled property for iframes

Comment: `tabindex =-1` removes element from the document tab flow (can't be tabbed)

Comment: @Ωmega - yes, but doesn't do anything for mouse clicks

Comment: Together with your point `1.` above it's pretty much all what is needed. Isn't it?

Comment: @Ωmega - I would think so as long as there is no javascript code setting focus into the iframe.

Comment: can't the iframe has its own hook/callback/event function that would be called when it receives the focus?

Comment: @Ωmega - yes an iframe could monitor when it got focus, but in the question, it would not know what to do when it got it.

Comment: Returning focus to previously focused element

Comment: @Ωmega - Except I don't think you can do that if the iframe is not the same origin as the host page since you can't run Javascript in the parent document.  And, I don't even think you have any way of knowing what previously had focus if it's in a different document with a different origin (because of security restrictions).  And it would be a bit unusual for an iframe to "assume" it knows what the parent wants the behavior to be too.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem that you're encountering is due to script in the iframe's document focusing one of its element, then one solution *may* be to use the iframe's [sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attribute to prevent the iframe's document from running script (that is, setting the attribute to a value that does not contain the flag 'allow-scripts'). Whether that's acceptable will depend on whether it will break other things, of course.

Comment: sandbox does not stop focus within an iframe